# converting coordinate space ios View

Tags: ios, space, point, coordinate

I have a UITableView with a few UITextField sub views. I was to get the coordinates of the UITextField from -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField. I've tried a bunch of the methods given on stack overflow but all seem to return the incorrect coordinate that i'm looking for.

My current method,

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(SettingsTextField *)textField{
{
CGPoint pointInScreen = [textField convertPoint:textField.bounds.origin toView:self.view];
```

It keeps returning that absolute coordinates, for example if i select the textfield at the bottom on the table it returns a point like 310. Because the keyboard hides this field I reset the frame on the UITableView to shrink. From there when i click the textfield in the row above it (keyboard still out) it returns something like 290. Because the entire frame has shrunk in height and the tableView has scrolled up to show the field I want it to return the coordinate relative to the top of the screen IE something like 80.

Comment: Can you try CGPoint pointInScreen = [textField.superview convertPoint:textField.bounds.origin toView:self.view];

Comment: I've tried every combination of superview, etc that I can think of and it seems to always return the same result